# Options for treating multiple partitions as one

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, lvm

I have an HDD partitioned with one partition used for media files, mounted somewhere on my system (which is a Debian Wheezy box). I would like to expand the space available for files in my mount directory - using an additional HDD, but without using another folder or a subfolder.

I understand LVM is an option - but for that I need to make the transition *without* moving or backing up any files (these aren't critical files, but obviously I don't want them gone). Can this be done?

Also, a better option would be if the partitions on the old and new disk simply both 'contributed' space to the same place, so that individual files would be written either entirely on one disk or entirely on the second, and that if I took out the second disk it would just be usable as-is without LVM. Is *that* possible?

**Update:** I tried [lvmify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lvmify), but it blurted an error and didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LVM is basically the only easy way of doing it.  You will have to move data around.

The only other way and, it **would require additional hard drives**, is a hardware or software RAID.  Obviously hardware is faster and uses no CPU, but can be expensive.  However you can add as many identical capacity hard drives as you have connectors for with this method.  RAID 5 would allow 1 hdd to fail without losing data and RAID 6 would allow 2 hdd to fail.  RAID 5 requires 3 hard drives minimum and RAID 6 requires 4.

I did the whole LVM thing for a while until I had a hard drive failure and released I had no redundancy with LVM.  If you use a LVM **make sure you have reliable backup method**.  For approx $10 a month you can use CrashPlan on linux.

Make sure you have a backup and then read this:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/how-to-create-lvm/

Comment: Why do think aufs is not an option?

Comment: http://aufs.sourceforge.net/   Has a disturbing note: "Aufs was rejected. Let's give it up." According to Christoph Hellwig, linux rejects all union-type filesystems but UnionMount.
I have to admit I don't know much about the file system itself, and would have to research it.

Answer (score 1):

LVM will do what you want, but sadly, not without some form of moving data around; take a look at this discussion of [union mounts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39850/which-union-filesystem-is-best-supported) for something that may be usable for what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

***Btrfs*** and ***ZFS*** are filesystems with multi-device support, therefore alternatives to Linux LVM. I have no experience with *ZFS*, I will focus on *btrfs* here.

> I need to make the transition without moving or backing up any files

[You can convert *ext3* or *ext4* to *btrfs* in place](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Conversion_from_Ext3). The process will take some time but it won't require additional device(s) to temporarily store your data. It will, however, require some free space on the original *ext* filesystem.

On the other hand, while doing such a trick it's always wise to have a backup anyway.

> I would like to expand the space available for files in my mount directory

You can expand your *btrfs* filesystem to additional device(s) with a command like

```
btrfs device add /dev/sdc /mnt
```

Read more here: [Using Btrfs with Multiple Devices](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices).

I've been using *btrfs* for few years now, done a conversion from *ext4* two or three times. My home server uses *btrfs* for the system partition in RAID-1 mode. Also I successfully expanded one of my data *btrfs* filesystems with additional devices when I needed a really large storage.

---

> Also, a better option would be if the partitions on the old and new disk simply both 'contributed' space to the same place, so that individual files would be written either entirely on one disk or entirely on the second, and that if I took out the second disk it would just be usable as-is without LVM.

There's ***[mhddfs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/mhddfs.1.html)***. I have never used it, yet it seems to fit your needs. As a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)-based filesystem it has some [security concerns you should know](https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/html/security.html). The main point:

> the filesystem itself executes with the access privileges of the process running it, not those of the process making use of the filesystem.

Note this doesn't apply to previously mentioned *btrfs* and *ZFS* because they don't use FUSE, they have a kernel support.